# SQL Connection grabbing my PC name

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Good day,

I don't seem to find the solution to this problem, maybe by the lack of knowledge  to express what I'm looking for.

I'm doing a SQL connection on ASP.Net on Visual.Net 2012, but everytime I try to connect to the SQL Database, it seems to grab my PC name instead of the username I am specifying on the Connection string. I got direct access to the server in-case it is server side problems. Here is a piece of my code.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    conexion = New MySqlConnection
    cadena = "Server=192.168.17.108;User id=root;Database=testing;Password=!Server2013"
    conexion.ConnectionString = cadena
End Sub
```

It is a local server for testing forms, I don't think it is important to hide user/password.

Thanks for your attention!

Edit: Forgot to mention that it is running on a IIS7 on Windows Server 2008

Comment: If you are running MySQL on the same host as the ASP.NET website, why not just used `localhost` as the Server parameter in the connection?

Comment: Does that space between 'user' and 'id' matter?

Comment: @Cameron Tinker It grabs something like this "root@WIN-ETCETCETC"

Comment: @DaveRLz Apparently not, tried both ways and still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a dodgy connect string. Take a look at this site: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ and you'll see that for mysql the connect string is more like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

So UID not 'user id', and Pwd not 'Password'

Hence, assuming all else is correct you should use:

```
Server=192.168.17.108;Uid=root;Database=testing;Pwd=!Server2013
```

Comment: Still nothing, this is the error:

Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
Access denied for user 'root'@'WIN-2IW8M0K0IHS' (using password: YES)
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'WIN-2IW8M0K0IHS' (using password: YES)

Error de código fuente:

Comment: Is the IP for WIN-2IW8M0K0IHS = 192.168.17.108 by chance? And that message (according to Google Translate - I only speak English) says 'Unhandled exception when running the current Web request. Check the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code' - that's fairly important information so you should post it!

Comment: "Access denied for user 'root'"

Comment: @GalacticCowboy thanks - so the question is, has remote root access been enabled for that database from WIN-2IW8M0K0IHS? I suspect not, check this page out for details: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Either that, or WIN-2IW8M0K0IHS is his local machine and Windows is sending it as the domain name.

Comment: WIN-2IW8M0K0IHS is the PC that host the MySQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I've set it to Localhost and it worked,(GENIUS), because the app was running on the server. Thanks Cameron Tinker.
And DaveRlz answer also worked to fix my connection string,
Thanks for the replies.